# Laravel 7.0 Cashier - Stripe Payment Exception

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm having problem on this Laravel Cashier Stripe payment. I need to combine the charge and new subscription as one so that when there is an IncompletePayment exceptions I can still get the stripe webhooks.

```
try{
  $user->charge(1000, $creditCard->id, [
                'description' => 'Premium Registration',
            ])
  $user->newSubscription('premium_member', $recurring)
          ->create($creditCard->id);

}
} catch (IncompletePayment $e) {

            $intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve($e->payment->id);
            $intent->confirm([
                'return_url' => url('api/payments-3d-success'),
            ]);

            return response()->json([
                'e' => $intent,
            ]);
        }
```

Another way is to catch the exception and build like laravel way of handling Incomplete exceptions.

```
try{

  $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
                'customer' => $customer->id,
                'items' => [[
                    'price' => $recurring,
                ]],
                'add_invoice_items' => [[
                    'price' => $oneTime,
                ]],
            ]);

}
//I need to catch the exception here from stripe and build like a laravel way like IncompletePayment exceptions
catch(Exception $e){
$intent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::retrieve($e->payment->id);
            $intent->confirm([
                'return_url' => url('api/payments-3d-success'),
            ]);

            return response()->json([
                'e' => $intent,
            ]);
}
```

Please let me know how you handle this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way you can do this using Invoice Items: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription#adding-upcoming-invoice-items